# Copy Data from Multiple Excel files into a single Sheet

Tags: vb.net

I have 70+ excel files. I want to copy data from `Sheet1` in all these files into a one consolidated sheet. Also, the file names for these 70+ excel files keeps changing.

Can someone help me with the code to automate this activity?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Interop or OleDB (or something else) to extracct and insert data in your Excel files. Then you can follow this steps :

1. Loop in your folder and open your Excel files.
2. For each file extract your data from your worksheet Sheet1 and stock this data in an object
3. Loop again and write your object in each file

Some links to help you :

- [VB.NET Excel Interop Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet)
- [OleDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [GetFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/t71ykwhb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)